# Kivy - Change custom widget color from App class

Tags: python, kivy

As the title states, I want to be able to dynamically change a custom widget programmatically at run-time from the app class. My initial approach was to call `changeCircleBackground()` on `self.root.circle_demo` but that does not change the color of the widget. Thanks for any advice.

Note: I left out where `changeWidget()` is called because I am using trio for async operations and it overcomplicated the example. I have verified `changeWidget()` has been executed successfully just without a change to the color of the widget.

Python File

```
class CircleDemo(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CircleDemo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background = get_color_from_hex(HEX_ORANGE)
    
    def changeCircleBackground(self, *args):
        with self.canvas:
            self.background = get_color_from_hex(HEX_BLUE)
        
    
class MainLayout(RelativeLayout):
    background = ListProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background = get_color_from_hex(HEX_BLUE)

class AsyncApp(App):
        
    def build(self):
        Config.set('graphics','show_cursor','0')
        Config.write()
        return Builder.load_file('ui/kivybox.kv')

    def changeWidget(self):
        if self.root.circle_demo:
                self.root.circle_demo.changeCircleBackground()
```

Kivy File

```
#: import rgba kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
MainLayout:
    circle_demo: circle_demo

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    CircleDemo:
        id: circle_demo
        size: self.size
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.25}
        size_hint_y: 0.5
        size_hint_x: 1

<CircleDemo@Widget>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background
        Ellipse:
            pos: 0, -root.height
            size: (root.width, root.height*2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a `background` `Property` for the `CircleDemo`, so its `background` ends up as just a simple instance variable, which does not effect a change to canvas color when changed. In order to get the automatic adjustment, you must use a `Property`. So, all you need to do is add the `background` `Property` to your `CircleDemo` class, like this:

```
class CircleDemo(Widget):
    background = ListProperty(None)
```